# How Mongoose is able to know that I've used await on invoking their function or not? [Edited]

Tags: javascript

[Old question] How can you know if your function concumer used await on invoking your function or not:

Maybe some magic like this:

```
function x(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       console.log(x.awaitWasCalled) // true  
   })
}
const a = await x()
```

I'm asking about that because I've seen Mongoose (a library) is able to detect weather you've called await or not, [HERE](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)
Here is what they're saying:

> Mixing promises and callbacks can lead to duplicate entries in arrays.
> For example, the below code inserts 2 entries into the tags array,
> *not just 1.

```
const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost', new Schema({
  title: String,
  tags: [String]
}));

// Because there's both `await` **and** a callback, this `updateOne()` executes twice
// and thus pushes the same string into `tags` twice.
const update = { $push: { tags: ['javascript'] } };
await BlogPost.updateOne({ title: 'Introduction to Promises' }, update, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

How Mongoose for example was able to detect that I'm using await or not?

[EDIT] ******* After sometime, I've noticed that the answers bellow doesn't actually answer my question.

Please before answering my question: please read their comment above, they're saying: " // Because there's both `await` **and** a callback, this `updateOne()` executes twice"

this means: if you didn't use await, and you passed in a callback, this code will be invoked once, BUT if you used await + callback, this code will be invoked twice, therefore: the question is: how they're able to know if I've used await or not?!

Again: **This means, if you didn't use await, this is going to invoke once, and if you used await, this is going to get invoked twice.**

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "called await"?  "await" is not a function...

Comment: call it whatever you like, it doesn't matter

Comment: What do you mean they are detecting it? They are not detecting anything in that code. It just runs each then() just like how promises work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I detect that await was mentioned before calling my function?

You can't. In fact, the function is called *before* `await` "kicks in". These two are the same:

```
await myFunction();

let result = myFunction();
await result;
```

`await` is not a different way to call a function, it simply operates on Promises, which of course are often returned by functions. I.e. it operates on the *return value* of a function.

> How Mongoose for example was able to detect that I'm using await or not?

Are they actually able to detect that? Nothing in the documentation you linked seems to indicate that.

What they (and you) could do is checking whether a callback is passed or not. If one is passed then they shouldn't return a Promise and vice versa. But I guess that's not how they want to design the API.

---

> This means, if you didn't use await, this is going to invoke once, and if you used await, this is going to get invoked twice.

Yes, but not because they detect anything but because `await` does something with the return value of the function. That's just how `await` works. So obviously, if you don't use `await` then the thing that `await` would do won't happen ;)

Here is an example:

```js
function someFunction(value, callback) {
  // Nothing in here does any "await" detection
  let array = [];
  if (callback) {
    array.push(value);
    callback(array);
  }
  return {
    then(resolver) {
      array.push(value);
      resolver(array);
    }
  }
}

(async function() {
  console.log('with await', await someFunction(42, () => {}));
  someFunction(42, array => console.log('without await', array));
}());
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, I believe that's exactly what they're doing

Comment: Wowowowwow, wait... I didn't have much time when I asked the question, but now after going back, man.. No, that's really not how their API is designed, they're really able to know that await is provided, see the example above in my question, they're passing a callback, and "await"ing the promise, they're saying that this is going to invoke the code twice, therefore two entires will go into the array.
man! really they're able to know you're using await or not, that's weird!

Comment: see their comment: " // Because there's both `await` **and** a callback, this `updateOne()` executes twice "

Comment: This means, if you didn't use `await`, this is going to invoke once, and if you used await, this is going to get invoked twice!

Comment: But *not* because they can detect that, but because they are both calling the callback and returning a promise. Let me provide an example....

Comment: Okay, Felix, thanks for you shiny ideas. I'll go now, I'll come back after 25 minutes to read your posts

Comment: @Ekmek: Updated.

Comment: OOOOOOHHHHH!!!!!!!! This answer deserves 1M up-votes!!! now I can say: await calls .then() automatically behind the scenes!! man! from where you got this?!

Comment: Hey Felix, If I'm understanding it correctly, could you please give me a good resource where it's mentioned what I'm saying "await automatically calls this behind the scenes".

Comment: MDN has an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#thenable_objects . And there is always the language specification though it it's not the most straightforward source. But to be really precise: That's not even a feature of `await`, it's how promises and "thenable" objects (an object with a `then` method) work. If you try to resolve a thenable object (e.g. `Promise.resolve(obj)`, then that process will call the `then` method. And `await` basically calls `Promise.resolve` on the operand.

Answer (score 4):

You've misunderstood what the documentation is saying.

It says that calling `then` will execute the query (but that passing a callback will *also* execute the query, so you shouldn't do both at the same time).

`await` is essentially alternative syntax for calling then (although it seems to do some magic with caching).

They don't detect `await`, they just have a method named `then`.

```js
const notAPromiseButThenable = {
    then: function () {
        console.log("Then called");
        return this;
    }
};

(async function () {
    await notAPromiseButThenable.then(() => null).then(() => null);
})();
```

Comment: Off topic: *"await ... it seems to do some magic with caching"* this made me curious, where can I read more about this?

Comment: I don't have a reference to hand, it is just behaviour I noticed when building a demo.

Comment: Thanks, Regardless whether they're detecting await/this or not, if you used await it will push an entry to the array, if you used a callback as an argument, it will push an entry into the array, if you used both, it will push two entries into the array. That's what they're saying in the example of the array.

Comment: @Ekmek: Right, so how does that relate to your question?

Comment: @FelixKling, Quentin mentioned a good example of how someone could do some behavior when .then is called. but this doesn't answer my whole question, I'm asking about how they're able to know if I used await or not

Comment: @Ekmek: But the answer to that is that they *don't* know.

Comment: See the first line of the answer. They don't (you only thought they did because you misunderstood the documentation) and they can't.